# Use macro to draw inside pgfplot/axis

Tags: macros, pgfplots, expansion

I would like to implement a gantt chart function inside `pgfplots`. To draw the tasks, I have a macro that calculates the start and finish time of a task. However, when I use multiple tasks, the values inside are overridden and as a result it only shows a single task.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\task}[7]{
    \pgfmathparse{#1/365+#2/12+#3}
    \edef\taskstart{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{#4/365+#5/12+#6}
    \edef\taskfinish{\pgfmathresult}

    \pgfmathparse{#7-0.4}
    \edef\bottom{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{#7+0.4}
    \edef\top{\pgfmathresult}

    \draw[blue,fill=blue!50!white] (axis cs:\taskstart,\bottom) rectangle (axis cs:\taskfinish,\top);
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=2011,xmax=2013,ymin=0,ymax=10] 
        \task{26}{1}{2011}{23}{6}{2011}{1} % this is not drawn
        \task{26}{1}{2012}{23}{6}{2012}{3} % only this is drawn
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I know that this is a question of expansion, but I have to admit that I do not know how to handle it within the `axis`.

Comment: Use directly `pgfgantt` package.

Comment: Related question for crosslink: [pgfplots - \foreach not behaving in axis environment - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170664/foreach-not-behaving-in-axis-environment?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem arises as you correctly have noticed due to the expansion of the variables. `pgfplots` collects all statements until `\end{axis}` and then executes them. Thus you need to make sure that the commands that are to contain data are containing the correct data! Your problem is that the data `\taskstart`, `\bottom`, `\taskfinish` and `\top` are defined to be the last value. That is from `\task<2>`.

Remember to consider all commands in `TikZ` or `pgfplots` terms to be already **fully** expanded for you to get the correct plot.

You can solve the problem by using this `\newcommand`:

```
\newcommand{\task}[7]{
    \pgfmathparse{#1/365+#2/12+#3}
    \edef\taskstart{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{#4/365+#5/12+#6}
    \edef\taskfinish{\pgfmathresult}

    \pgfmathparse{#7-0.4}
    \edef\bottom{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{#7+0.4}
    \edef\top{\pgfmathresult}
    \edef\tmp{%
        \noexpand\draw[blue,fill=blue!50!white] (axis cs:\taskstart,\bottom) rectangle
        (axis cs:\taskfinish,\top);}
    \tmp
}
```

The resulting image will be:

[image]